# TinyMCE Image Option in Context Menu Not Showing

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I've recently upgraded to TinyMCE 5 and want to be able to insert an image by right-clicking in the editor, (this worked in v4) but I'm only able to get the "Link (CMD+K)" option.

Here's my fiddle: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/VDhaab/3

Answer (score 3):

The context menu in TinyMCE 5 is context-aware, whereas in TinyMCE 4 it was just a hardcoded list that showed at all times. As such, TinyMCE 5 will only show options available for the current selection by default. So, if you want the old quick image context menu item back, then the simplest solution is probably going to be to declare a context menu configuration that ignores the current element. Here's an example: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/VDhaab/4

```
editor.ui.registry.addContextMenu('quickimage', {
  update: function(element) {
    return ['image'];
  }
});
```

What this will do is register a new `quickimage` [context menu section](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/contextmenu/#registeringcontextmenusections) that will always tell TinyMCE to render the `image` menu item. You could add other items to this if you wanted, such as `inserttable` which also used to show at all times in TinyMCE 4.